# Are the Winter Bash Hats Temporary or Permanent?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I was wondering: are the Winter Bash hats a temporary thing that disappears after some time, or are they here to stay and can we use them whenever we like?

Edit: If the hats disappear after a couple of weeks, will the hats we earn let's say in 2018 be available in 2019 or are we gonna start with a completely new set of hats from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look a the [FAQ](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What happens after January 1st?
>
> After January 1st, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Answer (score 4):

The hats last for a few weeks and then go away until next year's hats come out next December.

The end date is announced on the [Winterbash page](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/).  This year hats get put away on Jan 2, so take your screenshots by Jan 1.